# How to stub method that doesn't belong to class in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, stubs

I'm working a project that uses a notify method that does does not belong to a method. I want to stub this method to help speed up my spec and keep my log clean. How can i do this?

### lib/notify.rb

```
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'

def notify(*params)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `before` block in your specs to stub the :notify method on `subject`:

```
before do
  allow(subject).to receive(:notify)
end
```

Comment: Thats not working. I've also tried using `stub(:notify).and_return(nil)`

Comment: I've not seen the stubbing self, only `subject` or `described_class` or an explicit initialization of the class under test.

Comment: @yez Using `subject` instead of `self` worked, thanks